# S3 Image Upload Issue On ec2 AWS server instance

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, yii2

I am using *yii2, php 5.5.24*

**I am trying to upload images in s3 bucket from different ec2 instances with same credentials**

2 instances and localhost working fine but **1 instance is not uploading images** see the image below to see error which I am getting

[image: s3 Error]

I spend more than 3 days to solve this problem but get no success.

I found the same/similar issue [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=75517) **not solved**, [here](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/simple-s3-uploader/viewthread/12294) **not solved** and [here](https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class/issues/50) **not solve**

**EDIT**

**One more thing is, it was working before 1 week after that I am getting this error only on one instance and i have not update any version or library functions**

**Please Help Me Guys**, I don't have any idea what to do now.
its really a very major issue for me

***THANKS IN ADVANCE***

Comment: "Not uploading" is not helpful to solve this problem. What is the error message you are getting? How do you pass AWS credentials to your script? using .aws/config or IAMRole or in the script?

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have attached the screen shot of the error which belongs to `S3.php` . And I have also mention that it was working 1 week ago so, I don't thing how I m passing credential will help you solve this problem. Well I have done in Yii2 way.

Comment: The error message you are showing is in a code library, so it is not helpful. What command was YOUR code calling when it received the error?

Comment: If you're really sure that the code and configuration on all ec2 instances are the same the problem might not be related to the code. I would make sure that other ec2 related settings are the same as well. Did you check the firewall config in the ec2 console? Any other settings e.g. with s3 access rules? Are all ec2 instances in the same availability zone? etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have fixed this issue. I am posting my answer because it waste my whole week.

The issue was the network time protocol, we weren't allowing the traffic of UDP Port 123 for NTP to sync the time.

**We fixed that by editing the security group of EC2** and everything works perfectly :).